# Error during open the eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I want to open the eclipse. I get the error described below:

Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem?

```
!SESSION 2014-02-13 13:50:28.893 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1540
java.version=1.6.0_37
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pl_PL
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-02-13 13:50:30.981
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-13 13:50:31.228
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (40).
```

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please provide an answer and then accept it.

Comment: you can start with -clean option and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution. I'm deleting the file **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap** And it's works!